# sequelize include, join two associated tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have 2 models Assignment and Area in defined each one in seperate file like this :

```
./models
--Area.js
--Assignment.js
--index.js
```

Area.js :

```
    const Area = sequelize.define('area',{
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        }
        }, {
            timestamps: false
        });
     Area.hasMany(Assignment, { foreignKey:'areaId'});
```

Assignment.js :

```
    const Assignment = sequelize.define('assignment',{
        id: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
        }
      }, {
        timestamps: false
      });
    Assignment.associate = models => {
        models.Assignment.belongsTo(models.Area, {
            foreignKey: 'areaId',
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
        });
    };
```

When i try to find some assignments with areas information (join) with **Include** property i got an error saying that : **area is not associated to assignment!**

```
    Assignment.findAll({
            include: [{ model: Area }]
        }).then((assignments) => {
            res.status(200).json(assignments)
        }).catch((e) => {
            res.status(500).json({ error: e.message })
        })
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Area.hasMany(Assignment, { foreignKey:'areaId'});
```

So the column **areaId** should be in your `Assignment.js`. But can't see it in your `Assignment` model.

```
models.Assignment.belongsTo(models.Area, {
            foreignKey: 'areaId',
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
        });
```

Also this is correct only if you have a column called areaId in your `Assignment.js`

In conclusion you miss the `areaId` column in the `Assignment` model.

Comment: The column is automatically created when i lunch the script and so when i check the database, i can see that the **areaId** is automatically created and referenced to the **Area** table primary key (id). And that's what the official documentation says [Sequelize foreign Key Docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#foreign-keys) 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can stop the syncing properties of tables models file so that Sequelize do not drop and recreates the tables.

Comment: Also there are other options as well while creating relations like - sourceKey just like foreignKey but for other table

Comment: @BenAyoub then try to add that in your model and let me know what happens. (I mean mention the column in the model)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are missing the enclosing associate method:

```
Area.associate = models => {
    models.Area.hasMany(Assignment, { foreignKey:'areaId'})
};
```

and the column `areaId` should be in your `Assignment.js` too